# How to change name of row variable in a table

Tags: r

It's easy to change the names of the *rows* (e.g., with `rownames()`), but that's not what I'm after.  Consider:

```
> newTab <- xtabs(~as.factor(letters[1:2])+LETTERS[1:2])
> newTab
                       LETTERS[1:2]
as.factor(letters[1:2]) A B
                      a 1 0
                      b 0 1
```

I want to get this:

```
          upper case
lower case A B
         a 1 0
         b 0 1
```

But if I try:

```
> dimnames(newTab) <- list("lower case", "upper case")
```

I get an error:

> Error in dimnames(newTab) <- list("lower case", "upper case") :
>         length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the output of `str(newTab)`:

```
> str(newTab)
 xtabs [1:2, 1:2] 1 0 0 1
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ as.factor(letters[1:2]): chr [1:2] "a" "b"
  ..$ LETTERS[1:2]           : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
 - attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = ~as.factor(letters[1:2]) + LETTERS[1:2])
```

`as.factor(letters[1:2])` and `LETTERS[1:2]` are the names of the `dimnames` list. So you really want to set the names of the `dimnames` list, not the dimnames themselves.  You can do that via something like:

```
> dimnames(newTab) <- setNames(dimnames(newTab),c("lower case", "upper case"))
> # or
> names(dimnames(newTab)) <- c("lower case", "upper case")
> newTab
          upper case
lower case A B
         a 1 0
         b 0 1
```

Comment: or `names(dimnames(newTab)) <- c("lower case", "upper case")`

Comment: +1, thanks! @Arun, +1, want to make that an answer? It's a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks @gung. I think it's even better to edit it into this answer. It's not that different.